# My 2005 honda accord 2.4L low beam will not turn off

Tags: honda, accord, headlight

My 2005 Honda accord 2.4L low beam will not shut off. I tried to remove the battery cable for the whole night , but this didn't fix the issue. 
The light indicator on the dashboard will turn off by rotating the light switch, but lights won't go off.

any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a faulty headlamp relay - replace it and test again.

Answer (score 0):

If you removed the vattery cable and the lights stayed on, then you have a plotergeist! Impossible for light to work without power-check all circuits including sticking relay with a multi meter